# EF Core tracking individual property updates

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Using EF Core 1.1

**Entity Model**

```c#
public class ParentEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChildEntity> ChildEntities{ get; set; }
}


public class ChildEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentEntityId { get; set; }
    public ParentEntity ParentEntity { get; set; }
}
```

The `ChildEntity` can only be manipulated through an update to the `ParentEntity`.

So I have a repository class with an update method for the `ParentEntity`

```c#
public class Repository
{
    public async Task UpdateParentEntity(ParentEntity updatedParentEntity)
    {
        // Implementation Logic
    }
}
```

The Implementation logic is such that:

- IF a `ParentEntity.ChildEntity` EXISTS in the `updatedParentEntity` BUT NOT IN the database THEN add it
- IF a ParentEntity.ChildEntity`EXISTS in the database BUT NOT in the`updatedParentEntity`THEN set the`IsDeleted` property = true

I've done this via a "brute force" implementation which involved lots of loops, but I was wondering if Entity Framework and LINQ provide a more elegant way of handling this scenario?

Comment: Short answer - currently no, you are supposed to handle it yourself. Which in your case should be exactly 2 loops (i.e. not *lots*, but still loops).

Comment: Yeah 2 loops it is, not sure why I wrote lots! Thanks for the confirmation